# ¿Cómo cambiar el archivo.json que voy a leer segun el valor de la URL?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, json

Tengo una página estilo dropbox que lo que hace es mostrarme los archivos que están en una carpeta.

Cada carpeta tiene un archivo.json , que es de donde leo la información de cada carpeta. 
les muestro: 
carpeta1.json contiene esto :

```
{"nombreElemento":"imagen.png","tipoElemento":"imagen","fechaModificacion":"12/12/2012 00:45pm","fechaCreacion":"12/12/2012 01:45am","usuario":"jperez","tamanio":"5mb"}
```

y asi sucesivamente cada carpeta, la cuestión es que necesito que si le doy click a carpeta 2 , o carpeta 3 , me muestre lo que esta dentro de carpeta2.json o en carpeta3.json

ya tengo un botón que me recupera el valor de la url para así cambiar de lectura , solo que no se como pasarlo.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("El DOM ha sido cargado");
    console.log("Carpeta actual: " + $("#txt-carpeta-actual").val());

    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/obtener.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: $("#txt-carpeta-actual").val(),//se #txt-carpeta-actual 
                                            tiene el valor de la url que quiero que vaya cambiando, y en esta linea lo estoy enviando a obtener.php 
        success:function(respuesta){
            console.log("La respuesta del servidor es: ");
            console.log(respuesta);
            for(var i=0;i<respuesta.length;i++){
                if (respuesta[i].tipoElemento==='folder') {
                    $("#contenido").append(`<tr>
                    <td><a href="index.php?carpeta=home/${respuesta[i].nombreElemento}"><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>${respuesta[i].nombreElemento}</a></td>
                    <td>${respuesta[i].fechaCreacion}</td>
                    <td>${respuesta[i].usuario}</td>
                    <td>${respuesta[i].tamanio}</td>
                    </tr>`);
                } else if (respuesta[i].tipoElemento==='file') {
                    $("#contenido").append(`<tr>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-link" onclick="detalleRegistro('${respuesta[i].nombreElemento}');"><i class="far fa-file"></i>${respuesta[i].nombreElemento}</button></td>
                    <td>${respuesta[i].fechaCreacion}</td>
                    <td>${respuesta[i].usuario}</td>
                    <td>${respuesta[i].tamanio}</td>
                    </tr>`);
                }

            }
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

obtener.php tiene esto:

```
       <?php
         include("../class/class-elemento.php");
         $a= $__POST["ruta"];
         echo ELemento::listar($a);
       ?>
```

incluye la clase class-elemento que tiene la función listar(), que es a donde quiero pasar el valor de #txt-carpeta-actual

la funcion listar tiene esto :

```
    public static function listar($ruta){
        echo($ruta);    
        $archivo= fopen("../data/home.json", "r");//aqui es donde quiero concatenar el valor de #txt-carpeta-actual para que me cambie el home.json por el nombre de la carpeta actual, para que no solo me lea home.json , sino que alterne entre carpeta1.json o carpeta2.json , segun la que tenga #txt-carpeta-actual
        $respuesta = array();
        while(($linea=fgets($archivo))){
            $respuesta[] = json_decode($linea,true); 
        }
        fclose($archivo);
        return json_encode($respuesta);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Ya intentaste pasarle la variable?

```
$path = '../data/' . $ruta;

if( file_exists( $path ) ) {
  $archivo= fopen( $path , "r");
}
```

Ten cuidado con el `$_POST['ruta']`, tienes dos `underscore ( _ )`

Comment: voy a probar , gracias

Comment: nada amigo, no encuentra el archivo.json

Comment: Añadí una validación del archivo, en caso de no encontrar el archivo, entonces lo que está mal es tu ruta relativa.